# inherit from parent or project default

Tags: visual-studio, properties, project

In VS, in various project properties there is a checkbox "inherit from parent or project default". What does it generally mean?
To be more specific, what does it mean in Linker->Input->Delay loaded DLL ??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It generally means that this property is inherited from a more general property sheet. In fact, all values that are not in bold font are inherited this way.

Most of the myriad of properties are inherited from the global `$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props`. But one can actually add a user defined property sheet that can be reused across different projects to override some of the default properties.

To see this more clearly have a look at the `View->Other Windows->Property Manager` that displays the inheritance hierarchy and lets you add a custom property sheet to your project.

See the [MS docs on property inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/project-property-inheritance?view=msvc-170) for more info.